# Building a PC - Out of case BIOS only test - what hardware do I need?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, boot

I am building my PC and my friend told me I should try to plug a monitor in and see if the BIOS works and to make sure everything is not DOA and compatible. He's not online now, so my question is, what do I need to have plugged in?

What I currently think is:

- Motherboard
- RAM
- Video card
- Power Supply
- Monitor

Is there anything else I need to have? And do I need to install the CPU cooler? How long will it take before my i7-2600K (not overclocked, stock settings) overheats?

Also, I don't need a hard drive for a BIOS test yet, do I?

Comment: Yes install the cooler and make sure you don't ground the motherboard if you plan on testing it out of the case! only let metal touch it on the areas marked for screws.

Comment: What Kyle said.  Without a cooler installed you'll reach overheat in seconds.  Other than that you're correct; all the machine really needs to POST is the motherboard+RAM+CPU+power supply.  The others are just so you can see what the hell is going on. :)

Comment: Wow, ok. What does Kyle mean by "don't" ground it?

Comment: Also, when the stuff is in the case and running, how does the CPU cooler stay on when the mobo is mounted on its side?

Comment: @Keavon if you ground the motherboard you will fry it... more info:http://www.custompcblog.com/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-grounding-issues-spot

Comment: O wow @keavon if you are asking that you might want to consider waiting for you friend... however there are little holes around where the processor sits that four plastic clips will attach too. These will hold the heat sync and fan in place... Make sure you add thermal compound or your processor will still overheat very quickly

Comment: OH and @shinrai it's a 2600k so he probably needs the video card....

Comment: @Kyle means don't run the motherboard directly in contact with a metal surface, like the bottom of your PC case.  Put it on a block of wood or something similar.

Comment: @Keavon grounding the motherboard is if it touches the case in any place other than where the screws are. It will allow electricity to flow into the case and to other parts of the motherboard and also grounds your motherboard. It'll screw it up (I speak from experience, heh)

Comment: @Kyle - You can get a machine to POST without any video (depending on the motherboard).  It's just not terribly USEFUL.

Comment: @Shinrai true... it requires a mastery of beeps :P

Comment: I just wanted to see the BIOS screen. But I'm actually going to just put the thing together, as lugging the huge CPU fan around sounds like a big ordeal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the very least to get a successful POST (Power-On Self Test... what the BIOS does before booting) You need the Power supply, motherboard, RAM and CPU.  Although it might be useful to have a video-card & monitor attached so you can actually see the results :D

On a side note, there is no guarantee that components are not DoA even after completing a successful POST.  A POST only does the most rudimentary checks of hardware.  It will not tell you if your memory is properly matched to the board (there is a lot more to memory than simply matching the bus clock)  or if your power supply can provide sufficient power to the whole system under load... or many more things.  Only after assembling the whole computer, and installing an OS, and doing a "burn-in test" can you be sure all the bits are performing within tolerances.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Haha, you have 666 karma, time to fix that. B-)

Comment: much appreciated :D